# using separate() to separate numbers stuck together (Example: 201612) in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to separate the month_date_yyyymm column from this tibble:

```
     month_date_yyyymm postal_code zip_name          nielsen_hh_rank hotness_rank hotness_score
              <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1            201612       80230 denver, co                   8459         3420          74.0
2            201612       80503 longmont, co                 2233         6088          60.7
3            201612       38221 big sandy, tn               15014        12539          25.5
4            201612       13691 theresa, ny                 15586        14796          11.6
5            201612       19076 prospect park, pa           11777         1661          84.4
6            201612       18036 coopersburg, pa              8235         7870          51.5
>
```

I want the tibble to look like this

```
  year   month postal_code zip_name          nielsen_hh_rank hotness_rank hotness_score
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2016    12         80230 denver, co                   8459         3420          74.0
2 2016    12         80503 longmont, co                 2233         6088          60.7
3 2016    12         38221 big sandy, tn               15014        12539          25.5
4 2016    12         13691 theresa, ny                 15586        14796          11.6
5 2016    12         19076 prospect park, pa           11777         1661          84.4
6 2016    12         18036 coopersburg, pa              8235         7870          51.5
```

I can't figure out how to separate numbers that are stuck together, such as the month_date_yyyymm column. I know it has something to do with sep = in the separate function. Here is my code:

```
hotness_cleaned <- hotness %>% separate(month_date_yyyymm, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "2016", remove = T)
```

However, it's showing up like this:

```
     year  month postal_code zip_name          nielsen_hh_rank hotness_rank hotness_score
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 ""    12          80230 denver, co                   8459         3420          74.0
2 ""    12          80503 longmont, co                 2233         6088          60.7
3 ""    12          38221 big sandy, tn               15014        12539          25.5
4 ""    12          13691 theresa, ny                 15586        14796          11.6
5 ""    12          19076 prospect park, pa           11777         1661          84.4
6 ""    12          18036 coopersburg, pa              8235         7870          51.5
```

What is the correct syntax for separating numbers that are stuck together using "sep = "?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the position index in `sep`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
hotness %>% 
  separate(month_date_yyyymm, into = c("year", "month"),
         sep = 4, remove = TRUE, convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# year month postal_code          zip_name nielsen_hh_rank hotness_rank hotness_score
#1 2016    12       80230        denver, co            8459         3420          74.0
#2 2016    12       80503      longmont, co            2233         6088          60.7
#3 2016    12       38221     big sandy, tn           15014        12539          25.5
#4 2016    12       13691       theresa, ny           15586        14796          11.6
#5 2016    12       19076 prospect park, pa           11777         1661          84.4
#6 2016    12       18036   coopersburg, pa            8235         7870          51.5
```

#### data

```
hotness <- structure(list(month_date_yyyymm = c(201612L, 201612L, 201612L, 
201612L, 201612L, 201612L), postal_code = c(80230L, 80503L, 38221L, 
13691L, 19076L, 18036L), zip_name = c("denver, co", "longmont, co", 
"big sandy, tn", "theresa, ny", "prospect park, pa", "coopersburg, pa"
), nielsen_hh_rank = c(8459L, 2233L, 15014L, 15586L, 11777L, 
8235L), hotness_rank = c(3420L, 6088L, 12539L, 14796L, 1661L, 
7870L), hotness_score = c(74, 60.7, 25.5, 11.6, 84.4, 51.5)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```